# JDialog Pop Up warning not showing up

Tags: java, swing, popup, jdialog

I am trying to create a gui in which user puts some data using JTextFields. If the text fields are empty, a JDialog should appear with a message. The code was working fine yesterady but today it doesn't work. I have the main function here:

```
public class Ex1_Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Traveler currentTraveler = new Traveler();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI gui = new GUI();    
    }


}
```

and the GUI Class here:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JDialog j = new JDialog();
    JLabel err = new JLabel();
    JTextField uin1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField uin2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField uin3 = new JTextField();
    JTextField uin4 = new JTextField();
public GUI(){
    j.add(err);
    if(textFieldsempty(uin1,uin2,uin3,uin4)) { \\checks if the text fields are empty
       popUpError("You forgot to add a field");
    } else{
       //some other code
    }
}

public void popUpError(String str){
    System.out.println("Error");
    j.setVisible(true);
    err.setText(str);
}
}
```

The JFrame shows fine when the program starts and the console prints the word Error but the window doesn't show up, not even in the tiny default size. Any ideas why this is happenig would be really helpful.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Tip: the focus here is not on **Minimal** or **Short**. Look carefully at the *other* words.

Comment: 1) The JFrame should be specified as the parent of the JDialog. 2) You can just use a `JOptionPane` to display a message. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.